# Interpretation of sufficient statistic in the continuous case

Tags: statistics, probability-theory

A statistic $S = S (X)$ is called sufficient for $\theta$ if there is a $P_{X
\mid S} (\cdot \mid s)$ that doesn't depend on $\theta$.

So if $S(X)$ is a discrete random variable and we know $S
(X) = s$, then since $P_{X \mid S} (B \mid s) = \Pr(X\in B, S(X)=s)$, knowing more about $X$ tells nothing about $\theta$, as they are the same for all $\theta$, so we can say that knowing $S$ is "sufficient" to know $\theta$.

But in the continuous case or general case, you don't have $P_{X \mid S} (B \mid s) = \Pr(X\in B, S(X)=s)$, so how is a sufficient statistic still "sufficient" and in what sense?